# POST form params En API REST

Tags: c#, api, rest, post, diccionarios

Tengo que almacenar los datos en una BD que me manda una API, dicha API me manda una petición tipo POST a mi servise con los datos como parámetros
Literal la documentación me dice que 
**"los siguientes parámetros como form params"**

```
{
  "solicitud": {
  "dato1": "1",
  "dato2": "2",
  "dato1": "3",
  .
  .
  .
  "datoN": "N",
 }
}
```

Yo quiero tomar por ejemplo datoN y almacenarlo, pero no logro hacerlo. Mi controlador tiene el método de la siguiente forma

```
[HttpPost]
public string PostConfir(Dictionary<string, string>solicitud)
{
 Ads.GuardaDat("Guarda", "dato24");//Aquí se manda a la BD para provar que si llega al post

        try//Intento trabajar el diccionario 
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> respS = solicitud["solicitud"];

            string dat = solicitud["dato1"];//Esto me genera error 
            Ads.GuardaDat(dat, "dato25");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Ads.GuardaDat(ex.Message, "dato25"); //Esto se guarda en BD si hay error
        }


        return "";
    }
```

Como puedo trabajar con el dato o los datos? Tiene que ver la palabra form params se refiere a algún parámetro en especifico?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para usar REST incluiría la libreria de [Json.NET](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=json) que me permite realizar la siguiente conversión:

valor REST recibido  (asumo que esto es lo que recibes):

```
 string jsonStr = "{\"solicitud\": {\"dato1\": 1,\"dato2\": 2,\"dato3\": 8}}";
 var jObjeto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonStr);
```

ahora para acceder a los valores de tu json:

```
var dato3 =  jObjeto["solicitud"]["dato3"];//8
```

entoces tu controlador qudaria de la siguiente forma:

```
[HttpPost]
public void PostConfir(String solicitud){
 Ads.GuardaDat("Guarda", "dato24");//Aquí se manda a la BD para provar que si llega al post

        try
        {
            string jsonStr = solicitud;//"{\"solicitud\": {\"dato1\": 1,\"dato2\": 2,\"dato3\": 8}}";
             var jObjeto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonStr);

            string dat = jObjeto["solicitud"]["dato25"];
            Ads.GuardaDat(dat, "dato25");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Ads.GuardaDat(ex.Message, "dato25");
        }
}
```

ahora que si es un Diccionario lo que recibes solo convierte esta parte luego es igual

```
var jObjeto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(solicitud["solicitud"]);
```

no olvides incluir el espacio de nombre: **using Newtonsoft.Json;**

Saludos